# SVF2- How to get idRemap via rest api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Regarding [this post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids), I noticed there is viewer.model.idRemap which contains mapping dbis from SVF and SVF2. However this is in the viewer.

Is there anyway to get idRemap via the forge rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no REST API supporting getting the id map of SVF1 <-> SVF2. The only way I know currently is from Forge Viewer with using the new option `{needsDbIdRemap: true}` of [Viewer3D#loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) in v7.46. Sorry for the bad news.